# Not use await to run fastify/swagger

Tags: swagger, fastify, fastify-swagger

I try to use [fastify/swagger](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger) to build my API document, it works and this is my code.

The problem is, it only gets/route2, but cannot get /route1.
Any suggestion of it?

```
'use strict'

const fastify = require('fastify')()

// Define a sample route
fastify.get('/route1', async (request, reply) => {
  return { route1: 'world' };
});


const start = async () => {
  try {

    await fastify.register(require('@fastify/swagger'), {
      // openapi 3.0.3 options
      openapi: {
      ...
      },
    })

    // Define a sample route
    fastify.get('/route2', async (request, reply) => {
      return { route2: 'world' };
    });

    // Define a sample route
    fastify.get('/doc', opts, async (request, reply) => {
      reply.send(fastify.swagger())
    });
        
    await fastify.ready()
    await fastify.listen({ port: 3000 });
    console.log(`Server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```

Comment: Why do you call fastify.swagger before the listen?

Comment: I try to switch fastify.swagger() and fastify.listen(), but the API not defined inside start() is still not generated by swagger. I added my detail configuration in the original post, could you help with it? Or let me know if is there any example? thanks.

Comment: let me explain: `fastify.swagger()` returns a json that you are not using at all - so why are you calling that method?

Comment: I understand it, I revise my code and moved `fastify.swagger()` into a function, it works. But it can only show `/route2` inside `start()`, and it doesn't show `/route1`

Comment: Ok - now I understand your issue and I can explain it. I will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, it only gets/route2, but cannot get /route1. Any suggestion of it?

`fastify-swagger` uses [`onRoute` hook](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#onroute) under the hood.
This means that the hook function is executed synchronous when the event happens. *This is explained in detail in my Fastify book.*

So, in your code example you are adding the route before registering and awaiting the plugin: `await fastify.register(require('@fastify/swagger')`.

So, you must register the `fastify-swagger` before adding any routes to the `fastify` object instance.

Moreover, the route you created:

```js
    fastify.get('/doc', opts, (request, reply) => {
      reply.send(fastify.swagger())
    });
```

is the right approach to get the documentation, but since you are using `reply.send()`, the handler may be not `async` because of this documentation:
https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#promise-resolution

Comment: Thanks, I understand. And for the swagger json, I read the document, should I use `return fastify.swagger();` ?

Comment: If you prefer the async handler, yes it is correct 